# "Pre-sliced" - Is this used correctly?

Tags: word-usage

*Pre* means "previously" or "before". Therefore, *Pre-sliced* means "before being sliced" or "unsliced". Packaged, halved bagels would properly be referred to, then, as "Sliced Bagels".

Am I correct?

Comment: Bread is labeled "pre-sliced" to indicate that it has already been sliced. They could call it "sliced" but "pre-sliced" is more wordy and can give the impression that they took extra care or did more work in preparation of the product. Marketing terminology is often ungrammatical.

Comment: @Elijah Has bread moved on from being sliced, to being pre-sliced? I think that particular madness may not yet have reached the UK. I've an idea that such things used to be called 'Ready-xxx'. I'm thinking of things like concrete can be supplied (in the UK at least) as a 'ready-mix' rather than 'pre-mixed' and crisps with salt on are called 'Ready Salted' rather than 'pre-salted.

Comment: You could just as well (and more correctly) argue, based on what you wrote, that it means "previously sliced".

Answer (score 1):

> "Pre-sliced" - Is this used correctly?

Yes.

> "Pre" means "previously" or "before". Therefore, "Pre-sliced" means "before being sliced" or "unsliced". Packaged, halved bagels would properly be referred to, then, as "Sliced Bagels".

Nobody likes a pedant, Greg!

You're right that there's a difference in  meaning and that *pre-X* usually means "before X", as in *prewar* or *pregame*. But *pre-X* also often means "X before", in words like *prepaid*, *pre-owned*, and *pre-sorted*.

It looks like (and thanks to gstats for their comment):

- *pre-NOUN* means "before the NOUN" (*pregame*);
- *pre-VERB* words mean "VERB in advance" (*prepay*, *presort*, *preslice*);
- *pre-PARTICIPLE* words mean "PARTICIPLE in advance" (*prepaid*, *presorted*, *presliced*).

But don't hold me to it—I haven't checked them all!

Comment: I wonder if this is related to whether "pre-" is attached to a noun or an adjective, where "pre-*noun*" means "before *noun*" and "pre-*adjective*" means "*adjective* before"..

Comment: @gstats Not entirely. 'Pre-Abrahamic' means 'before the Abrahamic era', for example.

Comment: thanks @EdwinAshworth- my grammar isn't very good, I should have said past participle, as now indicated in the answer

Answer (score 0):

It means sliced before purchase. The "before" nature of "pre-" often doesn't have to refer to the word to which it is attached. Compare "pre-planned", which "planned in advance", not "before being planned".

Comment: Welcome to EL&U! Thanks for your answer, it is right and I agree with it, however, you do not cite any sources or provide evidence for your answer, if you could do so, your answer would be greatly improved.